# iText7 - Html2Pdf Jar and source

Tags: java, itext7

I am migrating functionality from iText5 to iText7 and we were converting html to pdf, In iText5 we had HtmlWorker/XmlWorker but in iText7 we have html2Pdf jar but I cannot check its sources in Eclipse, also there is no javadoc available, Does any one knows how we can check these API's and understand which one to Use to convert html2Pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the actual iText "pdfHTML" libraby then just use the available resources on the iText site: http://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfHTML

Specifically here is the documentation for converting HTML to PDF: http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-examples/converting-html-pdf

For even more info see the blog post from iText just 10 days ago: http://itextpdf.com/blog/pdfhtml-configuration-options

However if you sourced the library elsewhere then take note that there are other "html2pdf" libraries available that are not related to iText and they function differently.

Comment: When talking about XMLWorker in iText 5, then pdfHTML is most definitely it's counterpart for iText 7. However, contrary to XMLWorker, pdfHTML is _currently_ a closed source add-on to iText 7, so checking the source in Eclipse won't work. If you have added the iText Artifactory server as a secondary Maven repository, then you _should_ be able to get the Javadocs jar. If not, then I need more information.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, I found the iText7 has completely changed the API's and there was no javadocs online for html2pdf jar, I saw the examples that you guys attached but felt they were not good enough to understand what do the Api's do in broad level. @AmedeeVanGasse - I have set up the external rep as well as below<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>itext</id>
      <name>iText Repository - releases</name>
      <url>https://repo.itextsupport.com/releases</url>
    </repository>
 </repositories> but I cannot find the java docs for these API's.

Comment: It'll have to wait until after the weekend but I promise I'll take a look at the Javadocs, they _should_ be available. Although the documentation linked above is better to get you started.

Comment: @Amedee - Even I did Maven to download javadocs but cannot find it.

Comment: It'll have to wait until Monday.

Comment: I forgot about it yesterday. Making a JIRA issue *right now*.

Comment: Could you take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52736441/3169868